# Auto adjust TextView length which is in between an image and ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a `Listview`. Each row contains an `ImageView` , `TextView` and an `ImageButton`. 
I want the `ImageButton` to be of fixed size irrespective of the `TextView's` text length. 
This is supposed to be simple but i could not get it to work.

Here is my layout file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3jFa.png

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/androidAccountImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/droidalt" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profileName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/androidAccountImage"
    android:bufferType="spannable"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/strTryDemo"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/androidProfileEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileName"
    android:src="@drawable/edit_account_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the layout below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/androidAccountImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/droidalt" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/androidProfileEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/edit_account_button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profileName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/androidAccountImage"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/androidProfileEdit"
    android:bufferType="spannable"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/strTryDemo"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a ton. I guess the way Relative layout does onMeasure() has caused the trouble.